# Preserve Interpretation in Bash Variable

Tags: bash, quoting, interpretation

I'm trying to Preserve Interpretation in Bash Variable.

Example

when I run the following line at command prompt.

```
rm aaa 2>> error_file ; echo '<br><br>' >> error_file
```

I get the following (which is what I want):

```
rm: cannot remove `aaa': No such file or directory
```

If I put the error handling code in a variable it blows-up.

```
ERROR_HAN="2>> error_file ; echo '<br><br>' >> error_file"
rm aaa $ERROR_HAN
rm: cannot remove `"2>>"': No such file or directory
```

I have tried quoting a number of ways but no luck.  I can't seem to Preserve Interpretation for the `2>>` portion of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval`:

```
eval rm aaa ${ERROR_HAN}
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work fine.  Not sure why konsolebox feels it's unsafe

Comment: This doesn't just re-evaluate the contents of ${ERROR_HAN}, it re-evaluates the entire command line, leading to many confusing problems like needing do double-escape special characters etc. Also, if any part of the command is dynamically-generated (e.g. the filename), if it contains shell metacharacters they can be misinterpreted in confusing and/or dangerous ways. If you're willing to put something (like `eval`) at the beginning of the command (not just at the end), it'll be better to use a wrapper function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the command in a variable. Use a function instead:

```
rm_error() {
    rm "$@" 2>> error_file 
    echo '<br><br>' >> error_file
}

rm_error file1 file2 file3
```

See also: [BashFAQ/050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to create a variable that I can attach to the end of each command line in a daily batch job so that each command will either execute or write off the specific error to a file.

Comment: @MikeT You can still do it from the command line. Just add the function definition in your `.bashrc` (or similar), and next time you open a terminal the `rm_error` command will be available

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to have a function that I can append to the end of a number of different commands.  So that if any of the commands throw an error the function will catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll to use eval for that which is unsafe.

Better redirect it on a block, and use process substitution:

```
{
    rm aaa
    # ... other commands
} 2> >(
    while read -r LINE; do
        echo "$LINE"
        echo '<br><br>'
    done >> error_file
)
```

Another way which would write `<br><br>` only once at the end:

```
{
    rm aaa
    # ... other commands
} 2> >(
    if read -r LINE; then
        while
            echo "$LINE"
            read -r LINE
        do
            continue
        done
        echo '<br><br>'
    fi >> error_file
)
```

This one would write `<br><br>` even without an error, and only once at the end:

```
{
    rm aaa
    # ... other commands
} 2>> error_file
echo '<br><br>' >> error_file
```

Note if you're only using one command like `rm`, you don't have to place it inside a block, just `rm aaa 2>> >( ...`. And I think you'll only need one line:

```
rm aaa 2>> >(read -r LINE && echo "$LINE"$'\n''<br><br>' >> error_file)
```

Another:

```
EFILE=/path/to/error_file
rm aaa 2> >(read -r LINE && echo "$LINE"$'\n''<br><br>' >> "$EFILE")
```

Command-specific function:

```
EFILE=/path/to/error_file

function log_error_to_file {
    read -r LINE && echo "$LINE"$'\n''<br><br>' >> "$EFILE"
}

rm aaa 2> >(log_error_to_file)
another_command 2> >(log_error_to_file)
```

Multiple lines:

```
function log_error_to_file {
    while read -r LINE; do
        echo "$LINE"
        echo '<br><br>'
    done >> error_file
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to create a variable that I can attach to the end of each command line in a daily batch job so that each command will either execute or write off the specific error to a file

Comment: @MikeT How about a function instead? See the last part of my update.

Comment: @MikeT The questions is how would every line be sent to error file? Should `<br><br>` be added to every end, or after every command only? e.g. one for `rm`, another for `another_command`, etc..

Comment: I tried the function and receive the following:

$ ./test1
+ EFILE=/tmp/reports_cron
+ rm aaa
++ log_error_to_file
++ read -r LINE
+ set +x
$ ++ echo 'rm: cannot remove `aaa'\'': No such file or directory
<br><br>'
# works as it should but it hangs.
# I'm adding the '<br><br>' at the end of each response so that when I html email it to me it's not all run together.

Comment: Upon further review all of the code samples seem to work fine EXCEPT when I include set -x and set +x.  Cannot say I ever seen that before.  Thank you konsolebox !!

Comment: @MikeT I don't think it's a good idea to base from `set -x` when you're on a non-interactive bash. Better just use a literal string for every output. I added another modification of the function which bases itself from one of the previous methods. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer thanks.